# Force a find query in MongoDB / mongoose to use only a specific index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection where the documents have an additional index which is unique and is called `index`. I want to use this index only when I am performing certain search queries, and thus I pass this as a parameter to `hint`. Unfortunately, in the explanation received by `explain`, I can see that there were actually scanned 5 objects in the example below, while I was expecting these numbers to be 3. Here is the explanation output of a simple find query:

```
> db.collection.find({"index": {$in : [1, 4, 9]}}).hint({"index": 1}).explain();
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor index_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 3,
    "nscannedObjects" : 3,
    "nscanned" : 5,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 3,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 5,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "index" : [
            [
                1,
                1
            ],
            [
                4,
                4
            ],
            [
                9,
                9
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "hostname.local:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
>
```

So, is there a way to achieve what I want? This is not the behavior that I was expecting. On another related note, can I create a query plan and then force the use of that query plan so that `filterSet` in explain will be `true` (and thus instead of 5 documents only 3 will be searched)? Of course, if there is such a way I would be interested in knowing how to achieve this.

I am also adding the `mongoose` tag in the post because eventually I am interested in issuing such queries through mongoose.

Comment: Mr Mackey says "hints are bad, Okay". Query optimizers do just that. They "optimize" to the best result. If you have to force it then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Hi Neil, in principle I agree with your statement. In fact I know precisely what was designed in a wrong way and I mentioned it in this project in the past (from where the example was drawn), but out of "liberty" I did not make a big fuss to force my opinion. :) In any case, the question remains. I will come back to JohnnyHK's comment later tonight. First I want to finish some other stuff and perhaps do some more testing and go again through the MongoDB documentation. Thank you guys for your input so far, both of you.

Comment: An addition: The `index` was already a unique index, so the hint was really an overkill as an attempt to reduce the nscanned value. However, as JohnnyHK said, this is perfectly fine. I could verify the same output by looking at the `_id`s of these documents, and then retrying the query but instead of using the `index` I used the `_id` for my search. Then the explanation gave me again `nscanned` equal to 5 as well as `nscannedAllPlans` equal to 5. So, @JohnnyHK, if you write down your comment as an answer I will gladly accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an index is used (as in this case), [`nscanned`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#explain.nscanned) is the number of *index entries* scanned, not documents. [`nscannedObjects`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#explain.nscannedObjects) is the number of documents scanned and that's 3 so things seem to be working as expected.